# Understanding sentry-provider.ini file syntax

Tags: apache-sentry

**sentry-provider.ini**

```
[groups]
# Assigns each Hadoop group to its set of roles
engineer = engineer_role
ops = ops_role
dev_ops = engineer_role, ops_role
hbase_admin = hbase_admin_role

[roles]
# The following grants all access to source_code.
# "collection = source_code" can also be used as syntactic
# sugar for "collection = source_code->action=*"
engineer_role = collection = source_code->action=*

# The following imply more restricted access.
ops_role = collection = hive_logs->action=Query
dev_ops_role = collection = hbase_logs->action=Query

#give hbase_admin_role the ability to create/delete/modify the hbase_logs collection
#as well as to update the config for the hbase_logs collection, called hbase_logs_config.
hbase_admin_role = collection=admin->action=*, collection=hbase_logs->action=*, config=hbase_logs_config->action=*
```

I do not understand what is the syntax used here and what is its meaning?
From where do these groups and role values come from?
Why there are two = symbols in one line?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sentry depends on an underlying authentication framework to reliably identify the requesting user, i.e. Kerberos or LDAP. This tells you what **groups** a user belongs to.

The Sentry configuration then defines **roles**. This is a level of indirection that lets you share/re-use sets of privileges across multiple groups.

Group(s) can be assigned to a role, thus giving the users in those groups the privileges associated with the role.

**Privileges** are defined on (typically) Hive tables or Solr collections. This can be done at several levels (server, database and/or table in the case of Hive, or collection in the case of Solr).

So the following line:

```
engineer_role = collection = source_code->action=*
```

should be interpreted to mean: The engineer role has one privilege, which is: for the "source_code" collection, allow all actions.

When put together with group information:

```
 [groups]
 engineer = engineer_role
 [roles]
 engineer_role = collection = source_code->action=*
```

This means that any user in the "engineer" group (as determined by your authentication framework) belongs to the "engineer_role" role, and thus can perform any action on the "source_code" collection in Solr.

There are more detailed examples in the Cloudera documentation (CDH 5.8):

- Policy File https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-8-x/topics/cdh_sg_sentry.html
- Solr https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-8-x/topics/search_sentry.html